# Box - How to create a Service Account

Tags: box

I'd like to create a [Service Account](https://docs.box.com/docs/service-account) so I'd be able to authenticate with it with my app.
All I found is [this guide](https://cloud.app.box.com/s/qbiortmkztkrf9xxwrepwox0stbzrec1), but it doesn't say how to create such an account.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: It's not very clear in the docs but a Service Account == App.  See this thread:  https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Forum/Service-Accounts-how-to-create-one-and-how-to-use-it-through-NET/m-p/27175#U27175

Comment: @kendomen please post as answer so I can credit you with correct answer

Comment: The docs aren't that clear but a service account == app.  So if you create an app in the developer console and set authentication type to server authentication (jwt) and add your public key and get the app authorized in the admin console then you're ready to instantiate a service account with the following code:

Comment: JWTEncryptionPreferences encryptionPref = new JWTEncryptionPreferences();
        encryptionPref.setPublicKeyID(PUBLIC_KEY_ID);
        encryptionPref.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
        encryptionPref.setPrivateKeyPassword(PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD);
        encryptionPref.setEncryptionAlgorithm(EncryptionAlgorithm.RSA_SHA_256);

Comment: IAccessTokenCache accessTokenCache = new InMemoryLRUAccessTokenCache(MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES);

        BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection api = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppEnterpriseConnection(
                ENTERPRISE_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, encryptionPref, accessTokenCache);  // BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection == Service Account

Comment: @kendomen thanks, I figured all the details of this from their docs.
I'd like to reward you with the correct answer to this post, but thats only possible if you post an "answer", not a "comment".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs aren't that clear but a Service Account == App. So if you create an app in the developer console and set authentication type to server authentication (jwt) and add your public key and get the app authorized in the admin console then you're ready to instantiate a service account with the following code:

```
        String privateKey = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE)));

        JWTEncryptionPreferences encryptionPref = new JWTEncryptionPreferences();
        encryptionPref.setPublicKeyID(PUBLIC_KEY_ID);
        encryptionPref.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
        encryptionPref.setPrivateKeyPassword(PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD);
        encryptionPref.setEncryptionAlgorithm(EncryptionAlgorithm.RSA_SHA_256);

        IAccessTokenCache accessTokenCache = new InMemoryLRUAccessTokenCache(MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES);

        // BoxDeveloperAPIConnection == Service Account
        BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection api = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppEnterpriseConnection(ENTERPRISE_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, encryptionPref, accessTokenCache);
```

[image]

[image]